# Timeout when calling Textract from Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I want to use a Lambda function to call Textract on an image in an S3 bucket.  When I run the following in a SageMaker notebook, it works perfectly and takes only a couple of seconds.

```
import boto3
textract_client = boto3.client('textract')
textract_response = textract_client.detect_document_text(
    Document={'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'my-bucket-name', 'Name': 'my_image_file.png'}}
)
```

But when I run this in Lambda, the function times out.  (I have the timeout set to the maximum of 15 minutes.)

I wondered whether it was a [permissions issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731208/textract-cannot-read-object-from-s3-when-running-on-lambda), but the role for the Lambda function has both `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonTextractFullAccess`.  (In general, this Lambda function can access S3 files just fine.)

Both the SageMaker notebook and the Lambda function are in the same region (`us-east-2`).

Comment: Is your lambda under a VPC and security groups?

Comment: Yes, but the VPC was missing the Textract endpoint - see comment under accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your lambda is under a VPC.
You must add a VPC Endpoint for lambda:
VPC -> Endpoints -> Create endpoint

Search for com.amazonaws.us-east-1.textract / amazon / Interface in AWS Services. Add your VPC, Subnets ( don't forget to select subnet id ) and Security Group.

Comment: That was it!  The lambda was indeed under a VPC - but the VPC had an endpoint only for S3, not for Textract.  I added a Textract endpoint, and now it works.